# compare value in two rows in a column pandas

Tags: pandas, compare

I have a pandas df something like this:

```
           color          pct               days               text
  1         red            5                 7                 good
  2         red           10                30                 good
  3         red           11                60                  bad
  4         blue           6                 7                  bad
  5         blue          15                30                 good
  6         blue          21                60                  bad
  7        yellow          2                 7                 good
  8        yellow          5                30                  bad
  9        yellow          7                60                  bad
```

So basically, for each color, I have percentage values for 7 days, 30 days and 60 days. Please note that these are not always in correct order as I gave in example above. My task now is to look at the change in percentage for each color between the consecutive days values and if the change is greater or equal to 5%, then write in column "text" as "NA". Text in days 7 category is default and cannot be overwritten.

Desired result:

```
           color          pct               days               text
  1         red            5                 7                 good
  2         red           10                30                  NA
  3         red           11                60                  bad
  4         blue           6                 7                  bad
  5         blue          15                30                  NA
  6         blue          21                60                  NA
  7        yellow          2                 7                 good
  8        yellow          5                30                  bad
  9        yellow          7                60                  bad
```

I am able to achieve this by a very very long process that I am very sure is not efficient. I am sure there is a much better way of doing this, but I am new to python, so struggling. Can someone please help me with this? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation on a (now-deleted) suggested answer as comment:

```
# ensure numeric data
df['pct'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pct'], errors='coerce')
df['days'] = pd.to_numeric(df['days'], errors='coerce')

# update in place
df.loc[df.sort_values(['color','days'])
         .groupby('color')['pct']
         .diff().ge(5), 'text'] = 'NA'
```

Output:

```
    color  pct  days  text
1     red    5     7  good
2     red   10    30    NA
3     red   11    60   bad
4    blue    6     7   bad
5    blue   15    30    NA
6    blue   21    60    NA
7  yellow    2     7  good
8  yellow    5    30   bad
9  yellow    7    60   bad
```

Comment: thanks this works for me. How could I modify the code if I want to compare a non-numeric column instead of pct column please? All the rest of requirement is the same, just comparison is beween two non-numeric rows of a column named new_col. This new column has values like 'light', 'bright', 'dark', etc. So text should be changed if two rows differ in value, else, should stay the same

Comment: it depends how you want to compare, with unordered objects, you can use `ne`/`!=` combined with `shift` to check for difference. it depends on the exact use case.

Comment: I tried != but it is not working, gives error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: I asked the question in a detailed way here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72965750/compare-non-numeric-values-in-two-rows-in-a-column-pandas

Answer (score 1):

In the code below I'm reading your example table into a pandas dataframe using io, you don't need to do this, you already have your pandas table.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"""           color          pct               days               text
  1         red            5                 7                 good
  2         red           10                30                 good
  3         red           11                60                  bad
  4         blue           6                 7                  bad
  5         blue          15                30                 good
  6         blue          21                60                  bad
  7        yellow          2                 7                 good
  8        yellow          5                30                  bad
  9        yellow          7                60                  bad"""
),delim_whitespace=True)

not_seven_rows = df['days'].ne(7)
good_rows = df['pct'].lt(5)

#Set the rows which are < 5 and not 7 days to be 'good'
df.loc[good_rows & not_seven_rows, 'text'] = 'good'

#Set the rows which are >= 5 and not 7 days to be 'NA'
df.loc[(~good_rows) & not_seven_rows, 'text'] = 'NA'

df
```

Output

[image]

Comment: but text value for days 7 should not be replaced with good please. It should be left as it was before

Comment: Also, comparison should be between two rows of the same column of days. So, if pct for days 30 - pct for days 7 ge 5 then text 'NA' else text stays as is. If pct for days 90 - pct for days 60 ge 5 then text 'NA' else text stays as is.

Comment: sorry if I'm confused, but the text value for days 7 is not being replaced, it's starts off as "good" and ends as "good". you're right for your second comment, I didn't realize there needed to be comparison between the pcts of different rows. I think the answer by @mozway should work though

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.sort_values("days")
    return dd1.assign(text=np.where(dd1.pct.diff()>=5,"NA",dd1.text))

df1.groupby('color',sort=False).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out

```
   color  pct  days  text
0     red    5     7  good
1     red   10    30    NA
2     red   11    60   bad
3    blue    6     7   bad
4    blue   15    30    NA
5    blue   21    60    NA
6  yellow    2     7  good
7  yellow    5    30   bad
8  yellow    7    60   bad
```